# React.js Redirect to a link outside my routes and homepage

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react application that is hosted inside another application that manages authentication.

In my application I can see via a web service if the user is authenticated or not.

What I want to do is redirect the user to the main application if they are not authenticated.

My homepage is something like: "/BigApp/MyApp"

I would like to redirect the user to "/BigApp"

which will handle the authentication.

BigApp is not part of MyApp, it just has a link to MyApp.

I already tried using Redirect and tried to go up one level.

From what I understand Redirect only works with the components you have given a route.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
...
<Redirect to='../' />
```

When it redirects it stays in the same URL "/BigApp/MyApp"

Is there any way to achieve this using react router?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, there's no support, within the `<Redirect>`, to redirect to a external URL.

The way that you tried didn't worked because routes doesn't work as folders. Other point is that, as the `react-router` just works with a given group of routes(as you said), it won't work from "outside that box".

What you could is use the `window.location.assign()` method, that redirects your page to a given url passed as parameter.

Snippet below:

```js
const App = () => {
  return <button onClick={() => {window.location.assign("https://stackoverflow.com")}}>Click Here to Redirect</button>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the response. The thing is I am not using a button. I get the response from a fetch request and then I need to redirect the user.

Comment: You can call the method `window.location.assign()` within any function. The call inside the `onClick` of a button was just a example.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using  window.open('http://google.com', "_self", "", false);

Comment: @JoseLaboy If this answer helped you in any way, feel free to mark it as the solution